# Toen Rabbani in Halacha

Tags: beit-din-court

My understanding that a To’ein Rabbani is the equivalent of an attorney representing one in the beis din who has the required familiarity and certification of both state law and halacha.

Is this okay Halachikally? 
How does one become a Toen? 
Is a Toen simply a Dayan who was ordained with Yadin Yadin?

Comment: You asked three questions here, but the site format requires only one question per post. Please edit your second paragraph to focus on one question.

Comment: I think todays toen is like a barrister who puts forth legal arguments. I dont think this is correct in Jewish law. He has to put only the case. It is for the dayan to know all legal arguments and not for him to argue about them. If he is not satisfied with the dayan he can call the dayan to another bais din if he thinks he is wrong legally. The dayan does not even have to tell him his legal reasons like the shulchan aruch says if you dont know them ask your own rov we all use the same torah anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this profession is ancient (see Shu"t Rashba (part 1, paragraph 940), and possibly discouraged ([Hevel Nachalto 2:70](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%91%D7%9C_%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%95_%D7%91_%D7%A2)).

Toen requirements can be found [here](https://www.gov.il/he/departments/general/judge) and [here](https://www.gov.il/he/departments/general/certification_exams).

Being a Dayan may get you exempt from the exams, or some of them.